# MVC 4 EditorFor bool Checkbox always posting True

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a bool property in my model. Its value is false when rendering the view. But when I submit the form, the value of TRUE is being passed to the controller. I am using a custom js function to get the values from the form to submit to a controller action. I am not sure how to get the correct value from the checkbox.

My model property:

```
public bool RushOrderFlag { get; set; }
```

The view markup:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RushOrderFlag)
```

The HTML Rendered:

```
<input class="chkbx" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Rush? field is required." id="RushOrderFlag" name="RushOrderFlag" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="RushOrderFlag" type="hidden" value="false">
```

My JS function

```
function GetFilterCriteria() {
var Criteria = {};
$('#frmCriteria input').each(function () {
    Criteria[this.name] = $("#" + this.name).val();
});
return Criteria;
};
```

Even if in the console I put $('[name="RushOrderFlag"]').val(), after clicking the check box on and off, it is always returning true.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you submit with the checkbox unchecked, what value you got on the post?

Comment: it is always 'true'...but FYI, I am not doing a form submit. I am calling the javascript function posted above, then passing the Criteria object to an ajax call.

Comment: Ah, think I know why. For checkboxes, you need to check the checked property....the value is always the same.

Comment: if($("#frmCriteria input").attr('checked')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the hints...in the end it had to be a bit more complex due to the way the razor creates 2 input controls for the checkbox. So here is what I had to do:

```
function GetFilterCriteria() {
var Criteria = {};
$('#frmCriteria input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden') {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            Criteria[this.name] = this.checked;
        } else {
            Criteria[this.name] = $("#" + this.name).val();
        }
    }
});
return Criteria;
};
```

I don't like it because if I ever want a hidden input, this will skip that. But for now it works. I find it hard to believe that it has to be this difficult :(

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function GetFilterCriteria() {
var Criteria = {};
$('#frmCriteria input').each(function () {
    Criteria[this.name] = false;
    if ($("#" + this.name).is(':checked'))
        Criteria[this.name] = true;

});
return Criteria;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `.CheckBoxFor()` you will get an input element only.

for the checked property you can use:

```
$('#CurrentMailTemplateEnabled').get()[0].checked
```

to get the value by getting the DOM element first. At least that worked for me.