# MVC bool EditorFor value always true in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following bool on my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMonday, "Monday", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsMonday)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMonday)
    </div>
</div>
```

Which renders as this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsMonday">Monday</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsMonday field is required." id="IsMonday" name="IsMonday" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                <input name="IsMonday" type="hidden" value="false" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IsMonday" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Regardless of whether I check the box, in Chrome Dev tools the following results in true:

```
$('#IsMonday').val()
```

Why is this happening, and how can I find out whether the box is checked or not i.e. true or false, not just true.

This question is not helping me in case anyone recommends it:

[MVC 4 EditorFor bool Checkbox always posting True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887106/mvc-4-editorfor-bool-checkbox-always-posting-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally the minute I posted this I found the solution, as of JQUERY 1.6 the `attr()` method returns undefined which was another thing I had tried, this works:

```
$('#IsMonday').prop('checked')
```

Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: I have a bool property on my model and using the @Html.EditorFor. I couldn't get the value of the bool in jQuery. This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it always returns `true` is because `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` renders 2 inputs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsMonday" .. value="true" >
<input type="hidden" name="IsMonday" .. value="false" >
```

which is used for binding (unchecked checkboxes do not post back so the hidden input ensures a value of `false` is posted). To check its state, you can use

```
$('#IsMonday').is(':checked')
```